# MVC web app calling Application_Start multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am aware that changing the bin or using log4net in that folder can cause this to happen.
However not in this case. Is there some log or way to debug what is the culprit causing this to happen?

Comment: Does this issue occur on iis? does your project work fine locally?

Comment: https://www.tessferrandez.com/blog/2008/11/06/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-ETW-tracing.html Reading ETW should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Add as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: Turned out there was a log file that was being updated regularly from one of the components I was using!